# wp-eCommerce from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

Im trying to integrate WP eCommerce to one of my custom WordPress sites. Ive tried (fake) billing with a PayPal developer account to you know, test all this and the problem im having with is that, i can enter the payment and pretty much everything goes through but when im returned to my site to confirm, it always leads to a "page not found" error.

This page would be the one that gives the final option to confirm so the transaction goes through.

My question is, what am i missing? is there a page that one needs within a theme (like a 404.php or single.php or page.php) that im missing?

Im lost because since paypal wasnt working, i decided to test out the authorize.net api and dev tools and the same thing happened. I was able to enter payment details etc, but when it was time to pay and confirmation, it went back to my site to a 404/page not found.

What am i missing?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to create a new page inside wordpress and define it as fallback page in your wpsc paypal integration plugin

Comment: by any chance, is there any tutorial or something i can feed off of? i dont even know where to begin searching. thanks in advanced